# FactoryGirl sequence failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Factory Girl sequences not incrementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441505/factory-girl-sequences-not-incrementing)

It appears that FactoryGirl is not performing the sequence on `email` correctly, since I'm getting a failure when I try to create a user `6.times`. (Also to note: I have a uniqueness constraint on the `email` field.)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username 'asddfsa'
    sequence(:email) {|n| "asd01#{n}@gmail.com" }
    ...
  end
end
```

RSpec:

```
describe User do
  describe ".matches" do
    before :each do
      6.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :gender => 'Female', :seeking => 'Men') }
      4.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :gender => 'Male', :seeking => 'Women') }
      ...
    end
    ...
```

Failure:

```
Failure/Error: 6.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :gender => 'Female', :seeking => 'Men') }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `times'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441505/factory-girl-sequences-not-incrementing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dean Brundage's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441505/factory-girl-sequences-not-incrementing/) solved my problem...

Also I hadn't had Database Cleaner configured properly, which was also a blunder ;)