# Sequence within trait of FactoryGirl factory does not use main sequence counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Foo #{n}" }

    trait :y do
      sequence(:name) { |n| "Fooy #{n}" }
    end
  end
end
```

If I run

```
create :foo
create :foo
create :foo, :y
```

I get `Foo 1, Foo 2, Fooy 1`. But I want `Foo1, Foo2, Fooy 3`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple of hints from [smile2day's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874731/1185053) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572897/1185053), I came to the following solution:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :base_name do |n|
    " #{n}"
  end

  factory :foo do
    name { "Foo " + generate(:base_name) }

    trait :y do
      name { "Fooy " + generate(:base_name) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined two different sequence generators since they are not within the same scope.

I would not use :name for the generator. A name that implies a number seems more suitable.

```
sequence :seq_number
```

Include a transient attribute in the factory and assign the generated sequence nunber.

```
transient do
  seq_no { generate(:seq_number) }
end
```

Use the transient attribute for the 'name' attribute. The same applied to the trait version of 'name'.

```
name { "Foo #{seq_no}" }

trait :y do
  name { "Fooy #{seq_no}" }
end
```

Cheers,
Eugen